# Using Multi-core (-thread) processor for FOR loop

Tags: c#, multithreading, multicore

I have a simple loop for:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
{
    DoSomething(i);
}
int nopt = 8; //number of processor threads
```

I would like to do `DoSomething(1)` in processor thread 1,
 `DoSomething(2)` in thread 2
 ...
 `DoSomething(8)` in thread 8.

Is it possible? If yes than how?

Thanks for answers.

Comment: Why do you want to hard-code the threads? Why don't you use `Parallel.For`?

Comment: Have you checked `Parallel`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try `Parallel.For`:

```
  int nopt = 8;

  ParallelOptions po = new ParallelOptions() {
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = nopt,
  };

  // 9 is exclusive when you want i <= 8
  Parallel.For(1, 9, po, i => DoSomething(i));
```

*PLinq* (Parallel Linq) is an alternative:

```
  Enumerable
    .Range(1, 8)
    .AsParallel()
    .WithDegreeOfParallelism(nopt)
    .ForAll(i => DoSomething(i));
```

Comment: Thank you Dmitry, I was wondering if there is another method than Parallel.For loop.

Comment: @Monna L: *PLinq* can be convenient when you *play* with parallelism: it's very easy to add up options e.g. `.WithExecutionMode(ParallelExecutionMode.ForceParallelism)` switch back to sequential mode `.AsSequential()` etc.

Comment: @MonnaL you could use threads, but its far more complex than example of paralelism above

Comment: Cichy, can you put an example of how to do this using threads without parallelism, please?